# How do I prove that $\ker(T)$ is the subspace of $V?$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How do I tackle this question? I am really struggling to understand how matrices work and don't completely understand what a skew-symmetrical vs. symmetrical matrix means.

> Let $ V = \operatorname M_{ n \times n } ( \mathbb R ) $ and let $ T : V \to V $ be the mapping defined by $ T ( A ) = \frac {A + A^{ \mathrm t} } 2 $ for $ A \in V $. ($ A^{\mathrm t} $ is the transpose of $ A $.)
>
> Prove that $ \ker( T ) $ is the subspace of all skew-symmetric matrices in $ V $ and $ \operatorname{Im} ( T ) $ is the subspace of all symmetric matrices in $ V $.

Comment: To avoid downvotes and close votes, you might want to take a good look at guidelines for [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). For example, a good question should [provide context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) which your question is missing, such as: Did you attempt to solve this? If you failed, what happened?

Comment: In addition, take a look at [formatting and writing](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10992) suggestions: "Don't force someone to click on an external link just to see your question, it should be immediately visible after clicking on your title."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For $A \in V$ we have:

$$T(A)=0 \iff A+A^t=0 \iff A^t=-A.$$

2. If $A \in V$ is symmetric, then $T(A)=A$, hence $A \in Im(T).$
3. Let $B \in Im(T)$. Then there is $A \in V$ such that $B=\frac{1}{2}(A+A^t).$ Is $B$ symmetric ?